# Laptop will not power on normally if shutdown but can restart

Tags: laptop, motherboard, battery, power, reboot

I have an issue with my Asus laptop, I am able to restart the laptop, however, when I completely shutdown the laptop it is unable to turn on.
I have:

- Re-seated the battery
- Taken the battery out and have the laptop run only with the power cord (issue remains)
- Tested both the cord and battery to make sure they are functioning (they are)
- Power cycled the laptop both with the battery and without the battery
- Checked the capacitors on the mobo (all are good)

I suspect the laptop has some issue with discharging but I cannot seem to find the cause. The computer runs normally when it is powered on and has no issues with randomly shutting off. For what it's worth I have windows 10 installed with the current version 1903, also the issue happened out of the blue, no brownouts, physical damage or modifications with hardware.

To start it I have to unplug power cord and manually discharge (reseat the battery)

Comment: So how are you getting it to turn on, which it is clearly doing considering what you have said so far?

Comment: @music2myear I have to power cycle it each time regardless if the battery is in or not

Comment: Explain in detail how you get it to start please.

Comment: @Moab I have the laptop unplugged and manually discharged (reseat the battery)

Comment: Sounds like something on the motherboard has failed.